# Make GNOME 3 favorites launch a new window with left mouse button

Tags: gnome, gui

Left-clicking the icon of a running application on the GNOME 3 favorites panel switches focus to a running instance of that program. Right-clicking brings up a menu with a "New Window" option. Is there a way to make that the default behavior? I mostly use the favorites for launching new terminals.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I had that problem too. Very annoying.

Try this:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/67/dash-click-fix/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.